# compile the ffmpeg3.3 for Mac OS show ERROR: libmp3lame >= 3.98.3 not found

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I use my mac to compile the ffmpeg3.3 for Mac OS  according to https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS.I tried the first(which through Homebrew) and third(which builds it yourself) method,the first method is ok.

But the third, compiling FFmpeg myself and Installing dependencies with Homebrew.I don't know the meaning of this sentence [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th3BF.png)

after this step:

`./configure  --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libass \
--enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame \
--enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libopus --enable-libxvid \
--samples=fate-suite/`

terminal show:

`RROR: libmp3lame >= 3.98.3 not found`

when I use `locate libmp3lame.a`,it is at '/usr/local/Cellar/lame/3.99.5/lib/libmp3lame.a'.

I also try `--enable-libmp3lame --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib` to solve,but it is no effect.

How to solve this`ERROR: libmp3lame >= 3.98.3 not found`

Comment: What's wrong with just using the Homebrew method?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - It's ok to use the Homebrew method.But I want to rewrite the local code of ffmpeg,and then compile the local code of ffmpeg.The Homebrew method can not do this.

Comment: Try `--extra-cflags="-I/usr/local/Cellar/lame/3.99.5" --extra-ldflags="-L/usr/local/Cellar/lame/3.99.5/lib"`, or remove `--enable-libmp3lame` if you don't need to encode MP3 audio. If you just want to edit the ffmpeg code then a simple, plain `./configure && make` would be easiest.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I've already tried `--extra-cflags="-I/usr/local/Cellar/lame/3.99.5" --extra-ldflags="-L/usr/local/Cellar/lame/3.99.5/lib" `,that's still `ERROR: libmp3lame >= 3.98.3 not found`.When I remove `--enable-libmp3lame` and `enable-libxvid`,it can work.This method does not completely solve my problem, but thank you anyway.